# The nextval does not work when executing script in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm running the following script:

```
INSERT INTO Schema.columna (id_columna, n_nivel, n_esprincipal, s_cbasedatos, 
s_cmostrar, n_orden, n_tamano, n_formato, n_nivelorden, n_totaliza, 
n_esexpandible, n_cuenta, n_esvisible)
VALUES(sq_COLUMNA.nextval, 100022, 0, 'NOMBRESECTOR', 'NOMBRE SECTOR', 1, 25, 
 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1);
```

but it throws me the following error: ORA-02289: the sequence does not exist

the script of the sequence sq_Columna is found like this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE  "Schema"."sq_COLUMNA"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE   ;
```

why it says that the error sequence does not exist? should we create a trigger? I have no experience in oracle

Comment: Did you already run the sequence statement?

Comment: If you use quotes when creating the sequence then you have to use quotes when referencing it.

Comment: @NathanFarmer yeah! I already run the sequence statement! just take the script from oracle developer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff the sequence is already created!, the quotes are there because is extracted from oracle developer

Comment: The sequence is not preceded by "Schema" when you try to get the nextval. If you are logged on to a different schema, Oracle will look for the sequence in that schema.

Comment: `"sq_COLUMNA"` is mixed case. Consequently you must enclose it in double-quotes **whenever and wherever** you reference it. That's why you get ORA-02289 when you reference `sq_COLUMNA.nextval` without those double-quotes.

Comment: try Schema.sq_COLUMNA.nextval....  checkout the schema permissions...

Comment: @Tamil I have admin super user permissions

Comment: @ger - please check whether the required schema is present in all_sequences and dba_sequences table...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use of quotes solves it, if sequence exists and user has permissions.
Example:

```
 select sq_COLUMNA.nextval from dual;--> Throughs error ORA-02289
 select "sq_COLUMNA".nextval from dual;--> gives nextval
```

Quote:
"A quoted identifier begins and ends with double quotation marks ("). If you name a schema object using a quoted identifier, then you must use the double quotation marks whenever you refer to that object."

Ref: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF51129